# Trying to code a craps game and having trouble with logic

Tags: java, jframe, logic, simulation, dice

I have everything except the actual gameplay coded. I can't think of how to code the logic. I know the rules of craps, but I cannot (for the life of me) think of how to code it. Would I use a switch statement, or should I just go with an if statement? If you have any examples that would be great (seem to learn better by dissecting other people's code). Also if you do spot any errors just let me know.

```
private class PlayButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{

    public int rollDice()
    {
        int iDie = (int)(Math.random()*6) +1;

        return (iDie);
    }

    public void writeMessage(String sOutput)
    {
        jtaGame.append(sOutput);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        rollDice();

        int iDie1 = new rollDice();
        int iDie2 = new rollDice();

        int iSum = iDie1 + iDie2;

        String sRoll = "You rolled " + iDie1 + "+" + iDie2 + "=" + iSum + ".\n";
        String sOutput = "";
        int iPoint = 0;

        switch(iSum)
        {
            case 7:
            case 11:
                    sOutput = sRoll + "You win because you got a natural :)";
                    break;
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 12:
                    sOutput = sRoll + "You lost because you got a crap out :(";
            default:
                    sOutput = sRoll + "Point is: " + iSum + ".";
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: No one gives a crap (pun intended) about your visual components, because that code has nothing whatsoever to do with the question, so kindly remove all that code noise from your question. Leave only the bare minimum of code that you're having trouble with. Ideally create a [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org). Btw, nobody, and I mean *nobody* uses Hungarian notation in java - scrap the leading "i" from your int variable names

Comment: `int iDie1 = new rollDice();` Does this even compile?

Comment: @m0skit0 it had been compiling earlier, but no longer is. (don't know what changed because I didn't change anything from when it did compile).
**Bohemian** there you go, just the part I am having trouble with is now present. The only reason I use Hungarian notation is because of my professor.

Comment: Look again at the line I'm telling you. Does that looks good to you? If so, you better restart learning Java from the beginning because you're missing important basic concepts.

Comment: I'm not a Java person but what @m0skit0 is talking about is trying to create a new 'instance' of a local method, if I'm using correct Java terminology - it should just be a function call.

Comment: @m0skit0 it should be something like int iDie1 = rollDice(); shouldn't it?

Comment: Of course. `new` is for instantiating an object. Makes no sense to use it with a method.

Comment: Yeah I had been up way too long at that point and was overlooking the basics.